# Add annotations to a MapView in a loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps

I am trying to add some annotations to my mkMapView in this loop:

```
for (PFObject *fetchedCompany in companyArray)
{
       Store *store = [[Store alloc] initWithObject:fetchedCompany];
       [self loadStore:store];
       [store release];
}

- (void) loadStore:(Store *) store {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self getLocationFromAddressString:store.address];
    MapViewAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:store.name coordinate:location];
    [self.indexMapView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];
}
```

And this the getLocationFromAddressString method that convert the address to a location using google api:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr {
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSArray *items = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double lat = 0.0;
    double lon = 0.0;

    if([items count] >= 4 && [[items objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        lat = [[items objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        lon = [[items objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Address, %@ not found: Error %@",addressStr, [items objectAtIndex:0]);
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = lat;
    location.longitude = lon;

    return location;
}
```

When I send just one location always it works perfectly, but when I add annotations in my loop sometimes some locations could not be recognized and I got the error from my NSLog:

```
Address, Vallgatan 3 GÖTEBORG not found: Error 620
```

The thing is I am pretty sure about the addresses because when I tried them without loop they worked. Do you know how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've submitted too many queries and your request got rejected. See [Geocoding API V2 docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/#StatusCodes).

```
620:    G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES
```

*"The given key has gone over the requests limit in the 24 hour period or has submitted too many requests in too short a period of time. If you're sending multiple requests in parallel or in a tight loop, use a timer or pause in your code to make sure you don't send the requests too quickly"*